# Using a sliding window to identify and return the first success

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

I have and experiment where I am looking at bird visits to feeders. If they go to the correct feeder, it counts as a success. They are deemed to have learnt which feeder to visit once they are successful 16/20 visits (80%).

I want to write a piece of `R` code that goes through the full data frame by bird and identifies the first instance of 80% success with a moving window of 20 visits.

The code I have below works but it is clumsy. The end result is to obtain a tibble with each row representing a unique bird and the point at which they first reach 80% success.

```
# My attempt
library(tidyverse)

# Some sample data
data <- tibble(
  bird = rep("a121", 99), 
  success = sample(c(1,0), 99, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)),
  visit = 1:99) %>%
  bind_rows(tibble(
    bird = rep("b232", 99), 
    success = sample(c(1,0), 99, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.75, 0.15)),
    visit = 1:99)) %>%
  bind_rows(tibble(
    bird = rep("c211", 99), 
    success = sample(c(1,0), 99, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)),
    visit = 1:99)) %>%
  mutate(observation = 1:297) %>%
  select(observation, everything())

# Identify first time 80% success rate met with a sliding window of 20

res <- NULL 

slide.funct <- function(data, window, step){ 
  birds <- unique(pull(data, bird)) # Identify the birds in the data
  for (j in birds) {
    sub_data <- filter(data, bird == j) # Work with one bird at a time

    # Might need a line to ensure the data is ordered by time

    total <- nrow(sub_data)
    spots <- seq(from = 1, to = (total - window), by = step)
    result <- vector(length = length(spots))
    for(i in 1:length(spots)){
      result[i] <- mean(sub_data$success[spots[i]:(spots[i] + window)]) # Success rate by window
      position <- Position(function(x) x >= 0.8 , result) + 19 # First point at which success > 80%
    }
    res <- bind_rows(res, sub_data[position, ]) # Build up info for each bird
  }
  res <- res %>% mutate(observation = observation + 19) %>% 
    select(observation, bird)
  return(res)
}

slide.funct(data, 19, 1)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   observation bird 
#>         <dbl> <chr>
#> 1          53 a121 
#> 2         138 b232 
#> 3         237 c211
```

This is only the first stage of the process as there is more to do downstream. However, I'm not sure the above function robust enough. I looked at the 'zoo' package but didn't think it could help here. I'm also looking to use `tidyverse` code where I can, so if there are better options with respect to achieving the above, I'd be very happy to hear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the question used random numbers without setting the seed it is not reproducible so we used the reproducible data in the Note at the end.

For each bird, filter out the rows for which the 20 rows up to that point have a mean success of 0.80 or more and then return the first such row.  Just in case there are birds for which 0.80 is never achieved right join to the distinct birds.  If we were sure that every bird does achieve 0.80 or if we did not mind that birds that did not achieve 0.80 are excluded from the result then we could omit that line.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)

data %>%
  group_by(bird) %>%
  filter(rollmeanr(success, 20, fill = NA) >= 0.80) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(observation, bird) %>%
  right_join(distinct(data["bird"]), by = "bird")
## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##   observation bird 
##         <int> <chr>
## 1          46 a121 
## 2         127 b232 
## 3         218 c211
```

Note that the results from `slide.funct` in the question are not correct.  For example, 
we note that

```
mean(data$success[27:46])
## [1] 0.8
```

so 65 in the first row below cannot be correct and we see that the first column below is 19 too large in each case.

```
slide.funct(data, 19, 1)
## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##   observation bird 
##         <dbl> <chr>
## 1          65 a121 
## 2         146 b232 
## 3         237 c211
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form -- similar to question but added `set.seed`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

set.seed(123)

data <- tibble(
  bird = rep("a121", 99), 
  success = sample(c(1,0), 99, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)),
  visit = 1:99) %>%
  bind_rows(tibble(
    bird = rep("b232", 99), 
    success = sample(c(1,0), 99, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.75, 0.15)),
    visit = 1:99)) %>%
  bind_rows(tibble(
    bird = rep("c211", 99), 
    success = sample(c(1,0), 99, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)),
    visit = 1:99)) %>%
  mutate(observation = 1:297) %>%
  select(observation, everything())
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I meant to include the set.seed.

I need to play with the `zoo` package a little more. The code you posted above is exactly how I want to be able to write it.